# load content a comboBox with jQuery, AJAX and C++ Web server

Tags: jquery, c++, json, ajax, webserver

I try to load content while scrolling with jQuery and Ajax I have a problem with this code.

The CPP Webserver,method get request processor and response. This method select data from course table Database and convert result to json. Finally returns the result based on response.write

```
void processGetRequest(const char* path, const char* get_content, IHTTPResponse& response)
{
     if (strcmp(path, "/getCourseJson") == 0)
    {
        QLParam Qparam[] =
        {
            SQL_INT, &CourseID, sizeof(int),
            SQL_TEXT, Name, ARRAYSIZE(Name),
        };
        SQLReader sreader = mj_server->dbRead("SELECT CourseID, Name  FROM Courses;");
        std::map<std::string, std::string> mymap;
        while (mj_server->dbRecord(sreader, Qparam, ARRAYSIZE(Qparam)))
        {
            std::string str = std::to_string(CourseID);
            mymap.insert(std::pair<std::string, std::string>("ID", str));
            mymap.insert(std::pair<std::string, std::string>("Name", Name));
        }
        mj_server->dbFinalize(sreader);
        std::string mm = json::map_to_json(mymap);
        const char* mzm = mm.c_str();
        response.write(mzm);
    }
}
```

The jquery, I wrote a simple html file and put this script inside it

```
$(document).ready(function () {  
       $.ajax({  
           type: "get",  
           url: "/getCourseJson",  
           datatype: "Json",  
           success: function (data) {  
               var s = '<option value="-1">Please Select a Course </option>';  
               for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {  
                   s += '<option value="' + data[i].ID + '">' + data[i].Name + '</option>';  

               }  

               $("#Course_sel").html(s);  
           }  
       });  
   });
```

And now my problem, when I run the program, the get request is received by the CPP webserver and the result is sent correctly to jquery,But in the jquery, the received Json data is processed character by character, not object and element, so combo box fill with "undefined" text.

Please help me about this problem.

Thanks guys.